# PAM adding faulty module: pam_pwquality.so

Tags: ssh, authentication

I get the error below after running compliance through CIS script using USG audit on Ubuntu Server 20.04.4

```
PAM unable to dlopen(pam_pwquality.so): /lib/security/pam_pwquality.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
PAM adding faulty module: pam_pwquality.so
```

Comment: `dpkg -S /lib/security/pam_pwquality.so` will show you which package provides the file. `sudo apt install --reinstall` that package. Report a bug to CIS.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

sudo apt update

sudo apt install libpam-pwquality

Also reached out to Ubuntu to let them know.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `libpam-pwquality`

Answer (score 0):

Create a symbolic link at `/lib/security/pam_pwquality.so` which references to file `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_pwquality.so`. Oprn the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libpam-pwquality
cd /lib
sudo mkdir security
cd security
sudo ln -s /lib/security/pam_pwquality.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_pwquality.so
```